# Replace NaN's of one matrix with values of another matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, nan, na, missing-data

I have a 100 x 100 matrix that has 1800 missing values represented by `NaN`. I have another 1800 x 1 matrix that contains all these missing values. I want to plug in these values from my 1800 x 1 matrix to the first matrix.

I tried;

```
data_matrix[is.na(data_matrix)] <- predicted_values[1,]
```

But this did not work.

Perhaps the safest option would be to do it based on row/col names? Because both of my matrices have corresponding row/col names. Here's an example of what I mean:

**data_matrix**

```
  VAL.T  VAL.U  VAL.V  VAL.W
A 10.5   NaN    203    902
B 20.9   343    12     NaN
C 32     22     NaN    90
D 12     NaN    NaN    23.1
```

**predicted_values**

```
VAL.U:A 65
VAL.W:B 21
VAL.V:C 23.9
VAL.U:D 11.1
VAL.V:D 78
```

The order that values are arranged in predicted_values might also be helpful: i.e. values in predicted_values are arranged in a way as if we're moving from the beginning of first row in data_matrix to the end of first_row and then moving to next row. This is the way NaN values should be replaced.

Comment: Do you have a data.frame with `predicted_values`? or is it a matrix with row names `VAL.U:A` etc?

Comment: `predicted_values` is a matrix with the aforementioned row names (VAL.U:A) etc. `data_matrix` is a matrix with row names such as A, B, etc. and column names as VAL.U, etc. Therefore, row names of predicted_values are column names and row names of data_matrix separated by colon.

Comment: If the values in the second matrix are already ordered (as showed in the example) then `data_matrix[is.na(data_matrix)] <- predicted_values[,1]` should work. Note the `[,1]`

Comment: It's not working at all, it fills in NAs with repeated values, i.e. all NAN's are replaced with the first value in predicted_values.

Comment: Based on your input example, it works for me

Comment: @akrun. It doesn't appear to me that your method should succeed, since the ordering of 'predicted_values' presumes assignment on the basis of a `byrow` order.

Answer (score 2):

Since `predicted_values` stores the values by row then column, while matrices normally store their values column-wise, you should do transposition.

```
a=t(data_matrix)
a[is.na(a)]=predicted_values[,1]
data_matrix=t(a)
```

Comment: This is such a fragile strategy. It depends entirely on number _and_  the sort order of the values in the predicted_values object being exactly "in sync" with the NA positions. It makes no use of the information in the first column. And while we're on the topic of order, why wouldn't if be : `a[is.na(a)]=predicted_values[,2]`?

Comment: It is explicitly told that "The order that values are arranged in predicted_values might also be helpful: i.e. values in predicted_values are arranged in a way as if we're moving from the beginning of first row in data_matrix to the end of first_row and then moving to next row. This is the way NaN values should be replaced." I made use of this.

Comment: "why wouldn't if be : a[is.na(a)]=predicted_values[,2]" - because predicted_values have just one column.

Comment: I used read.table and without a header it gets read as 2 columns, but I now see that description in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use a two-column matrix built from splitting the first predval column as the first (single) argument to "[<-" and predval's second column as the second argument:

```
idxm <- cbind( sapply( strsplit(as.character(predval$V1), ":"), "[",2), 
                 sapply( strsplit(as.character(predval$V1), ":"), "[",1) )
dtm[ idxm ] <- predval$V2
dtm
#-----------
  VAL.T VAL.U VAL.V VAL.W
A  10.5  65.0 203.0 902.0
B  20.9 343.0  12.0  21.0
C  32.0  22.0  23.9  90.0
D  12.0  11.1  78.0  23.1



dput(predval)
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("VAL.U:A", 
"VAL.U:D", "VAL.V:C", "VAL.V:D", "VAL.W:B"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = c(65, 21, 23.9, 11.1, 78)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

dput(dtm)
structure(c(10.5, 20.9, 32, 12, 65, 343, 22, 11.1, 203, 12, 23.9, 
78, 902, 21, 90, 23.1), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), c("VAL.T", "VAL.U", "VAL.V", "VAL.W")))
```